# Head&Tails game simulation between 2 players

Tags: java

I know that this game is " popular " here because it's a good start for newbies like me , but i am really stuck with a problem.

This is how my program looks in this moment (main program):-

```
public class Proiect1 {
   public static void main(String [] args){

        System.out.println("Enter the number of throws: ");
                Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
                        int n=sc.nextInt();
                             game p1=new game();
                             game p2=new game();
                                int score1=0,score2=0;
                                int coin;

  System.out.println("The game rules:"+"\n-if coin =1 that means   
                    HEAD"+"\n-if coin =2 that means TAILS"+"\nEnjoy the game!");
  System.out.println("The first player will throw the coin!
                      Let's see if the second player can quess the coin side!");
       for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
           p2.Player2Choice();
           coin=(int)((Math.random()*2)+1);
                                                                                       if(coin!=p2.getDecisionPlayer2()){
             System.out.println("You lost!"+"Coin side was: "+coin);
             score1++;
           }             //close if                                   
           else{
               System.out.println("You win! "+" Coin side was: "+coin);
               score2++;
           } //close else

       System.out.println("Player1 won: "+scor1+" times");
       System.out.println("Player2 won: "+scor2+" times");
       }close for
       System.out.println("Win rate for player1: "+(int)((scor1*100.0f)/n)+"%");
       System.out.println("Win rate for player2: "+(int)((scor2*100.0f)/n)+"%");
  } //close main
}     //close class
```

My problem is that i want to switch the Player1 with Player2 if Player2 guess the coin side and the reverse. I had an  idea but the result was a failure!

I really need some help, thanks for your time!

Comment: And what is your question? You can't just dump code or demands and expect us to get to work without any help from you.

Comment: You're indentation is a mess, if that helps

Comment: How can i make the switch between players?? that is my question..

Comment: Well i am a newbie in programming after all:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only 2 players game. So you can simply set Boolean value to switch between players.
E.g.
Initialize boolean as

**boolean isPlayer1Chance = true;**

When after any chance alter value as inside for loop,

**if(isPlayer1Choice){

//Do player 1 play

}else{

//Do Player 2 Play

}

isPlayer1Choice = !isPlayer1Choice;**

Comment: Thanks Jack for your help and support:)

Comment: WC Zamfi, but remember from next time only paste problem statements and not the entire code :)